# Unable to changes switch on off in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
 Widget getList(BuildContext context) {
if(profileViewModelController.listOfSchedules.isNotEmpty){
  return Container(
    height: 350,
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: profileViewModelController.listOfSchedules.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        var schedule = profileViewModelController.listOfSchedules[index];
        var dayStatus = schedule.dayStatus?.toLowerCase() == "open" ? true : false;

        ScheduleItem item = ScheduleItem(week: schedule.day, startTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 8, minute: 0), endTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 0),dayStatus: dayStatus);
        listItem.add((item));
        return Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                item.week!,
                style: black40012,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Switch(
                value: item.dayStatus!,
                onChanged: (bool? value) {
                    setState(() {
                    item.dayStatus = false ;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                item.dayStatus! ? "Open" : "Close",
                style: black40012,
                // print((item).toString());
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              ),
              child: DropdownButton<TimeOfDay>(
                underline: SizedBox(),
                isDense: true,
                value: item.startTime,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                items: buildTimeDropdownItems(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    item.startTime = value!;
                  });
                },
                style: black40012,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 10,),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              ),
              child: DropdownButton<TimeOfDay>(
                underline: SizedBox(),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                isDense: true,
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                value: item.endTime,
                items: buildTimeDropdownItems(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    item.endTime = value!;
                  });
                },
                style: black40012,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
  );
} else {
    }
```

This is my widget i am calling api based on api data i am updating switch value on and off  when i first time launch app then i am able to get status switch value based on ON and OFF working but when i try to change switch on click from on to off or off to on from widget its value not changing state can any one help me what i am doing wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: You are only changing `item`'s value, not the actual `profileViewModelController.listOfSchedules[index]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use switch like this

```
Switch(
            value: item.dayStatus!,
            onChanged: (bool? value) {
                setState(() {
                item.dayStatus = value;
              });
            },
          ),
```

The value is not changing because you are setting the value of day status to `false` inside the `setstate`

but you have to set the new value to the day status which you are getting from `onChanged` function.